# Separate header from curl when saving to file

Tags: php, wordpress, curl, header

I download a json file using curl and I have this script working fine. But I need header from CURLOPT_HEADER saved this to a separate file or added into output array and not into same file, is this possible? Now everything saves into this file and I need to separate header from file witch is a unnecessary process.

```
    /** 
 * Send a GET requst
 * @param string $get 
 * @return string 
 */ 
public function curl_get(array $get = NULL) 
{  

    $url = $get['host'] .'/'. $get['service'];
    $filename = PLUGIN_BASE . 'logs/'. $get['service'] .'_'. $this->nice_filename();
    $fp = fopen($filename, 'w');

    unset($get['host']);
    unset($get['service']);

    $defaults = array( 
        CURLOPT_URL => $url. (strpos($url, '?') === FALSE ? '?' : ''). http_build_query($get), 
        CURLOPT_HEADER => 1, 
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE, 
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
        CURLOPT_FILE => $fp
    ); 

    $ch = curl_init(); 
    curl_setopt_array($ch, ($defaults)); 
    if( ! $result = curl_exec($ch)) 
    { 
        //$result = curl_error($ch); 
        $filename = trigger_error(curl_error($ch)); 
    } 

    curl_close($ch); 
    fclose($fp);

    $arg = array(
        'file'=>$filename,
        'curl_id'=>$fp
    );

    return $arg;
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can use `CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION` to specify a function that gets called like so for each header received:

```
function readHeader($ch, $header)
{
    // do something with the value of `$header`

    // you must return the length of the header that you received
    return strlen($header);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Header is separated from data with a line containing just \r\n, so you can use explode to get the data. Take out the CURLOPT_FILE from the curl options, explode the returned string to get separate parts, and then save it to files yourself.

```
list($header , $data) = explode("\r\n\r\n" , $result , 2);
```

or you can use open another file and use CURLOPT_WRITEHEADER option to write headers into separate file